# Toilet in basment

Tags: toilet

Our toilet in the basement is a throne which means there are 2 steps up to the toilet seat and 2 feet above the concrete floor.

What is the code for this situation?.

I was told since it is grandfathered 60 years ago it would pass inspection.

Comment: Where are you located?

Comment: I deleted my answer based on the comment by Daniel Griscom...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a legal question based on your local building codes.

Comment: Welcome to Home Improvement! Unfortunately, local code questions are off-topic. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how better to contribute here.